# epoll on apache c module

Tags: c, apache, apache-modules

I want to create `apache c module`.
I want this `c module` to do `epoll`. Is it possible?
It means that I want specific thread that will be blocked on this `epoll`.

Alternately, if I could somehow make the `apache` do the `epoll` by itself and then will call my handler, it will do it.

My target is to be noticed when something happens.
Is there another way of doing it?

Comment: Instead of telling us the solution you want to use (`epoll`), why not tell us what the actual problem you are trying to solve is?

Comment: My target is to be noticed when something happens. I want to be subscribed on something, and when I get notified I want to change a parameter on another c module